# Building Complex Lambda Expression (Select property over object list over object)

Tags: c#, lambda

I need to build a complex lambda expression in runtime, here is the cenario:

I have a interface named IHasCostCenter with a string property named CostCenterId:

```
public interface IHasCostCenter
{
    string CostCenterId { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a example of a class that implements this interface:

```
public class Contract_Rate: Entity, IHasCostCenter
{
    public int ContratoId { get; set; }
    public string CostCenterId { get; set; }
    public int Percentage { get; set; }
}
```

There is two situations where I need to build a dynamic lambda expression, the first one is that if the class contains the IHasCostCenter interface, it should filter the items based on a list of CostCenterId's and the item's CostCenterId, this is the expression built:

```
if (Interfaces.Any(x => x == typeof(IHasCostCenter)))
{
    var sValues = User.CostCenters.Select(x => x.CostCenterId).ToList();
    var sValuesType = sValues.GetType().GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();

    ParameterExpression Parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    Expression Property = Expression.Property(Parameter, typeof(T).GetProperty("CostCenterId"));
    Expression Contains = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Contains", new[] { sValuesType }, Expression.Constant(sValues, sValues.GetType()), Property);

    MethodCallExpression whereExpression = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "Where",
        new Type[] { items.ElementType },
        items.Expression,
        Expression.Lambda(Contains, Parameter));

    items = items.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(whereExpression);
}
```

There is a second cenario, and this one I was not able to solve, it happens when the object contains a list of objects that implements IHasCostCenter interface, as the classes described above, in that case the lambda expression should select the Contract_Rate list from the Contract, then select the CostCenterId for each Contract_Rate in the list and see if any of the CostCenterIds is in the User.CostCenters.Select(x => x.CostCenterId).ToList().

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

It's way easier to construct the tools needed to let you write this query using lambdas than it is to try and create the entire expression manually.

The simplest case is where the items in the query itself implement `IHasCostCenter`.  In that case you can simply constrain the generic argument to be `IHasCostCenter` and then use a lambda:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Foo<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> query)
    where T : IHasCostCenter
{
    var validIDs = User.CostCenters.Select(cc => cc.CostCenterId);
    return query.Where(item => validIDs.Contains(item.CostCenterId));
}
```

If you take as input a selector that selects the item in question to an `IHasCostCenter`, with the assumption that the query has a property of that type, and then write your own lambda to turn an `IHasCostCenter` into a query determining if it's a valid ID, you can `Compose` those two lambdas together.  If you write such a `Compose` method then the implementation of your existing code becomes:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Foo<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> query,
    Expression<Func<T, IHasCostCenter>> selector)
{
    var validIDs = User.CostCenters.Select(cc => cc.CostCenterId);
    return query.Where(selector.Compose(
        item => validIDs.Contains(item.CostCenterId)));
}
```

Transforming this to accept an `IEnumerable<IHasCostCenter>>` instead becomes quite trivial:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Foo<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> query,
    Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<IHasCostCenter>>> selector)
{
    var validIDs = User.CostCenters.Select(cc => cc.CostCenterId);
    return query.Where(selector.Compose(list =>
        list.Any(item => validIDs.Contains(item.CostCenterId))));
}
```

So then how do we write a `Compose` method?  What we need to do is accept two expressions, and replace all instances of the parameter of the composing expression with the body of the composed expression:

```
public static Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>
    Compose<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFirstParam), "param");

    var newFirst = first.Body.Replace(first.Parameters[0], param);
    var newSecond = second.Body.Replace(second.Parameters[0], newFirst);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>(newSecond, param);
}
```

This uses the following method to replace all instances of one expression with another:

```
public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}
internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still understanding your solution, In your 'Foo' method, the selector should be the list of property 'CostCenterId', right? I think it fits quite well, I will build the select expression. Thanks for the time and attention, any news I'll update here.

Comment: @E.Leal Since there are two overloads the selector can select out either a property of type `IHasCostCenter` or a property of type `IEnumerable<IHasCostCenter>>`.  Either will work just fine.